# How to get the dropped item's id on drop event jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, drag-and-drop, droppable

When I drop something to jquery droppable, I want to get the dropped items' id. When I did it like this:

```
$("#here").droppable({
        tolerance: 'fit',
        accept: ".one",
         drop: function(){
            id = $(this).attr("id");
            alert (id);
        }
    });
```

it of course alerted the id of the droppable `here`. How can I select the id of the dropped div?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change your drop function to take two arguments: event, ui

```
function(event,ui){
    var draggable = ui.draggable;
    var id = draggable.attr("id");
}
```

The draggable that is being dropped is represented by ui.draggable

Found in the jquery ui docs for droppable.

Comment: thanks! I was wondering why it didn't work when i did it like `tasid =  $(ui.draggable).attr("id");`... forgot `(event,ui)`

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
   $( "#droppable" ).droppable({
          drop: function( event, ui ) {
                var draggableId = ui.draggable.attr("id");
            var droppableId = $(this).attr("id");
          }
        });
      });
```